# Border-Radius Flaw in upper right and lower left

Tags: css

I created a border around my header for a simple start I was making to a page.  I doesn't seem to matter what numbers I use, I get a little white triangle in the upper right corner and a flaw, hard to describe, in the lower left.  Sometimes it also becomes a triangle depending on numbers used in border-radius and border.  Anyone else get flaws in those corners?

This is fixed in IE with -webkit-, but even worse in FF if I use -moz-

```
.banner {
            width:100%-8px;
            height:110px;
            background-color:#80BCFF;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border-radius:8px;
            border:8px ridge silver;


        }
```

Comment: What is `width:100%-8px`? Are you posting SCSS/SASS, or did you intend to make that a `calc` expression? Post a minimum example, including, HTML in a fiddle or StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: I was using it to calc because I'm a beginner and was trying to avoid overflow so the border would be visible on the right.  Today I learned about box-sizing so I changed it but still have the same defects in those 2 corners.

Comment: .banner {
 width:100%;
 height:120px;
 background-color:#80BCFF;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:8px ridge silver;
}

Comment: <div class="banner">
 <h1 class="heading">Test1</h1>  
 <p class="text">Test2</p>
 <img src="images/funny.JPG" class="thepic" />
  
</div>

Comment: To answer the question, I was trying to keep the right hand side of the border and being new I used -8px for that.  Today I learned about box-sizing.

Comment: Try editing your question with this code rather than updating comments. And if possible, use either a fiddle or SO's "Snippets" to provide a live example of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  As I keep learning I found a better way to do the banner anyway.  :)